# What uniform is this man wearing (circa 1940's)?

Tags: identification, uniform

This is a photograph of my husbands grandfather. He was born in 1920 and in the image he appears to be about 20 ish making the picture 1940 ish.

We believe he was born in Poland and later moved to the UK.

Any help to identify the uniform would be amazing. Thank you.

[image: Man in uniform with crushed beret; large cross prominent on left breast]

Comment: Hello. It is displayed under my text. I hope I uploaded correctly.

Comment: Any chance of a better quality photo? It would help folks here to help you.

Comment: When did he move to the UK? Is this likely to be a Polish uniform or a UK uniform?

Comment: The cap badge looks very much to me like the kind of eagle badges worn by the Polish Army in Exile, which wore (basically) British-style uniforms with Polish insignia.  The breast patch looks like that of a medical unit.

Comment: @kimchilover Never saw any breast patch like that for medics. And the center seems to have sth round in the corners? So more like a war decoration? (Basic shape even 'a bit' like VC?)

Comment: @LаngLаngС I was looking at pix like https://www.warrelics.eu/forum/polish-armed-forces-west-polskie-si-y-zbrojne-na-zachodzie-1939-1947/uniform-unit-insignia-polish-army-exile-1939-45-7-a-540702/ But maybe that is a shoulder patch and not a breast patch?

Comment: I wish I had a clearer photo..this is as good as it gets I'm afraid. I'm told he met his wife (my husbands grandmother) in a camp - I'm not sure if this was in Poland or it could have been Germany.  His grandmother was taken off the street in Poland when she was 16 (around 1939). There was a suggestion he was in the British army but I can't find any evidence of this. They married in the UK some time later in 1948. Thanks so much for you help.

Comment: @kimchi lover, I scanned through the warrelics link and came a across a female version of the jacket that looks very similar but without the patches. The caption reads "Here is rarely seen "Polska YMCA " patch on a female BD.". What is a "female BD"? Sorry if that's a silly question.

Comment: Maybe BD = "Battledress", the standard UK term for combat uniform.

Comment: @kimchilover Despite all the blur and the breast patch? Since this is less 'in-Poland', dress, but more like [this](https://www.polishmilitaria.net/product-page/ww-ii-british-battle-dress) (flat breast pockets!), we see the single stripe rank on top the shoulders but nothing on the sides, your eyes see the infantry version of the Polish eagle, it seems to me _an_ answer, even if partial, might be ready?

Comment: Gosh I'm sorry, I don't know what this means.

Comment: @Kath181  Here's the Wikipedia page for the British Army Battledress (BD) in WW2   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Battledress

Answer (score 4):

The photo is blurry and the provided backstory is thin on details, so this partial answer is conjectural.  One thing is clear to me, though: this is a picture of a happy man.

The subject is wearing what looks like a uniform of the [Polish Army in Exile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_Armed_Forces_in_the_West), which played an important role in World War II. (There is a section on these uniforms in a book [Military Uniforms in Europe, 1900-2000](https://books.google.com/books?id=FE4DBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA83&lpg=PA83&dq=polish+army+in+exile+rank+insignia&source=bl&ots=fUv1lmhtwI&sig=ACfU3U2FUN_8gZvBut9W4TF-rZspXtdwQA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjBt-_E6rj1AhVhjIkEHbq1A9IQ6AF6BAgrEAM#v=onepage&q=polish%20army%20in%20exile%20rank%20insignia&f=false), by R. Spenser Kidd, pp.82-83.)  This army was equipped by the British, and the basic fabric and cut of the uniform was the same as the British Army's. The shape of the breast pockets and the beret are two obvious features illustrating this.

The cap badge, however, looks to me like the standard Polish Army cap badge, illustrated [here](https://militaria.co.uk/product/free-polish-army-army-in-exile-cap-badge-white-metal-original/) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_Land_Forces#/media/File:POL_Wojska_L%C4%85dowe.svg).  The smooth curved bottom outline of the badge is visible in your image, and the lumpy upper outline in your image seems consistent with the spiky outline of the badge.

The rank shown on the shoulder straps seems to be that of a "Starszy szeregowy", private first class.

The meaning of the badge on the breast pocket is unclear to me.  It looks a bit like a medical unit badge, but I think unit badges  were usually worn on the shoulder.

I suggest you contact the [Pilsudski Institute](https://www.pilsudski.org.uk/en/) in London to see if they can tell you more about your relative and his photograph. They might be able to look his name up in various unit rolls.

Comment: This is amazing   Thank you so very much!! This will mean so much to his living relatives. I will continue to research as you have suggested. A million thanks once again 